# jOOQ disable DAO and POJO generation

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, pojo, jooq

My project requires me to generate DAOs and POJOs on my own. Have to do certain modifications to it. My SRS says that I have to use jOOQ. I am using it for the first time; I understand that jOOQ generates POJOs and DAOs on its own, but I couldn't find a way to disable it.

I could't find anything in jOOQ's documentation that would help me with this. Could someone tell me how to disable jOOQ from generation DAO and POJO but still provide the Records.

The Maven pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
<artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
<name>jOOQ</name>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.jooq.org/inc/LICENSE.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
    <!-- [pro] xxx
    xxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxx
    xxxx [/pro] -->
</licenses>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- XJC-generate JAXB artefacts. Contribution is the courtesy
             of Sergey Epik -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- If this causes trouble in your Eclipse m2e lifecycle configuration, try using
                     http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/, instead of the official m2e Eclipse
                     plugin
                  -->
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <strict>false</strict>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>jooq-runtime-3.3.0.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>org.jooq.conf</generatePackage>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xxew</arg>
                    <arg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</arg>
                    <arg>-Xxew:delete</arg>
                    <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                    <arg>-Xdefault-value</arg>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                   </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-default-value</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.2</version>
                    </plugin>              
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.5.3</version>
                    </plugin>      
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                    <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        javax.persistence;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.log4j;resolution:=optional,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <_versionpolicy>[$(version;==;$(@)),$(version;+;$(@)))</_versionpolicy>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <!-- add the generated manifest to the jar -->
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the build is using gradle . I dont know how will that affect the changes either.

Comment: Please add to your question configuration file

Comment: @AntonDozortsev which conf file should i attach to it? are you refering to the pom.xml for jOOQ?

Comment: Yes provide the code of Maven `pom.xml` where you config you `maven-jooq-plugin`

Comment: Parent project **jooq-parent** `pom.xml` have configuration of `maven-jooq-plugin` ?

Comment: this is the one! .. though i figured it out. the project is built using gradle . so config for all dependencies are redirected to build.gradle . jooq {
        generator {
            generate {
                relations = true
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = false
                daos = false
                fluentSetters = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = '...'
}  that file isnt accessible from the project directory but i could edit it here!! .. thanks!! @AntonDozortsev

Comment: Good!. For more info read **[Run generation with Gradle](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/)** and **[jooq-codegen configuration](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/#N27A7F)** where you can see how to disable any options

Comment: @phoenix: Did the above comments answer your question? You know that you can provide your own answer here on Stack Overflow. For future visitors, it would be interesting to see what the real answer was...

Comment: @LukasEder ok! i will retype the answer here! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the project is built using gradle . so config for all dependencies are redirected to build.gradle . 
the extract from the build file that helped me mutate jooq properties are:

```
    jooq 
    { 
      generator 
        { generate 
           { relations = true 
             deprecated = false 
             records = true 
             immutablePojos = false 
             daos = false 
             fluentSetters = true 
       } 
      target { packageName = '...' }
```

that file isnt accessible from the project directory but i could edit it here!!